# COUNTIF cells CONTAIN line break

Tags: count, google-sheets, line-breaks

I wish to count how many cells contain exactly one, two, three, four or five lines, respectively.
*(meaning: In one field I wish to display the no. of one-lined cells; in another field the no. of two-lined cells; etc. The counts are kept apart like this)*

Inside a cell such multiple lines will have line breaks in between them (the character `char(10)` if I'm not wrong) (such line break is made by typing `Alt+Enter`). Thus I'm trying to count these linebreak characters. **No** line breaks in a cell means **one line**, **one** line break means **two lines**, etc.

A simple counter like `=COUNTIF(D31:D;char(10))` will of course not work since it looks for cells that *only* contain the `char(10)`. So first of all I need some kind of a `CONTAIN` command.

Also, when this works, I wall have to be able to count how many of these characters there are in a cell.

Do you have a good way to run this? Thank you.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-specific-characters-in-a-cell

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something similar to this function to get a count of the line breaks

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),""))
```

This gives the following result with this example:

```
"Hello
world"      1
"Model
Major
General"    2
Foo Bar     0
```

Then you can count if the column B is not zero.